# Create password protected Windows user with Salt

Tags: windows, automation, salt-stack

I need to create a password protected windows user account to run a windows service with this user account. Therefore I tried this sls snippet:

```yaml
tcagent3-user:
  user:
    - present
    - name: tcagent3
    - password: tcagent3
    - groups:
        # German administrators group is used
        - Administratoren
    - system: True
```

Unfortunately the created user is not password protected. Looking at the docs, password seems not used by windows at all. I saw other snippets using `passwd` but that doesn't work either. Has anybody an idea to achieve this via salt. I can imagine if salt doesn't offer this out of the box there might be a command line call I could use as a workaround?